# How to extract href and text from a attribute within div

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the names and links of free courses from Harvards website at https://pll.harvard.edu/catalog/free using Python and BeautifulSoup

I have gotten the names of each course but I am having trouble trying to extract the link to the course.For example, for CS50's Introduction to Game Development, this is the html for the link to the courses page:

```
<div class="field field--name-title field--type-string field--label-hidden field__items">
        <h3 class="field__item"><a href="/course/cs50s-introduction-game-development" hreflang="en">CS50's Introduction to Game Development</a></h3>
  </div>
```

I am trying to get the "/course/cs50s-introduction-game-development" part in the a attribute, for each of the courses listed on the page.

This is the code I currently have that gets the name of the course:

```
#gets the soup of the given url
def get_data(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

#gets the name and skill from each course and prints them
def get_all_content(firstURL):
    url = firstURL
    for i in range(1, 10):
        soup = get_data(url)
        print("PRINTING PAGE: " + str(url))
        course_names = soup.findAll("h3", attrs={"class": "field__item"})
        skills = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "field field--name-title field--type-string field--label-hidden field__items"})

        for course, skill in zip(course_names, skills):
            print(course.text + "\n" + skill.text)
        url = f'http://pll.harvard.edu/catalog/free?page={i}'

        print("PRINTING NEWLY GOTTTEN URL: " + str(url))
        #sleep(randint(2, 10))


get_all_content(firstURL)
```

I tried the following solutions to get the href, gotten from online and researching. The closest I have come to is this, added within my first for loop above:

```
 for div in soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "field field--name-title field--type-string field--label-hidden field__items"}):
      page_link = div.findAll("h3", attrs={"class":"field__item"})
      print("PRINTING LINK: " + str(page_link))
```

which prints, for the first course, this:
PRINTING LINK:`[<h3 class="field__item"><a href="/course/cs50s-introduction-game-development" hreflang="en">CS50's Introduction to Game Development</a></h3>]`

What I was expecting is only this part:"/course/cs50s-introduction-game-development"

I have tried many solutions that I have found online but I often get errors such as find_all cant be used here or None does not have a find attribute or somethign along those lines. I am very new to Python(started this week)and I am not sure how to improve this further, the syntax is very confusing and I have researched it and gotten to this stage. I have already reduced it down to the h3 and it is very close to what I am looking for and I feel like the solution is so simple but I have spent 2 days straight working on it and no success. I appreciate any help. How do I extract the href from an a attribute from within an h3 from within a div?

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! Quick question - why did you choose to use a requests.Session? From searching online it seems that it "keeps" my session on the website so that I can reuse it later on, would that be best suited if for example I want to scrape a website I need to login to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to obtain that data:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

big_list = []
for x in range(9):
    try:
        r = s.get(f'https://pll.harvard.edu/catalog/free?page={x}')
        is_next_page = bs(r.text, 'html.parser').select_one('li[class="pager__item pager__item--next pagination-next"]')
        courses = bs(r.text, 'html.parser').select('div[class="views-row"]')
        for course in courses:
            course_name = course.select_one('h3[class="field__item"]').get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')
            course_url = 'https://pll.harvard.edu' + course.select_one('h3[class="field__item"] a').get('href')
            big_list.append((course_name, course_url))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
df = pd.DataFrame(set(big_list), columns = ['title', 'url'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    title   url
0   CS50's Understanding Technology     https://pll.harvard.edu/course/cs50s-understanding-technology
1   Global News & Technology Leadership in Challenging Times    https://pll.harvard.edu/course/global-news-technology-leadership-challenging-times
2   China’s First Empires and the Rise of Buddhism  https://pll.harvard.edu/course/chinas-first-empires-and-the-rise-of-buddhism
3   Deploying TinyML    https://pll.harvard.edu/course/deploying-tinyml
4   Science & Cooking: From Haute Cuisine to Soft Matter Science (chemistry)    https://pll.harvard.edu/course/science-and-cooking
...     ...     ...
123     PredictionX: John Snow and the Cholera Epidemic of 1854     https://pll.harvard.edu/course/predictionx-john-snow-and-cholera-epidemic-1854
124     CS50's Computer Science for Business Professionals  https://pll.harvard.edu/course/cs50s-computer-science-business-professionals
125     CS50's Understanding Technology     https://pll.harvard.edu/course/cs50s-understanding-technology-0/2023-05
126     Innovating in Health Care   https://pll.harvard.edu/course/innovating-health-care
127     Data Science: Productivity Tools    https://pll.harvard.edu/course/data-science-productivity-tools/2023-10

128 rows × 2 columns
```

See documentation for [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and for [BeautifulSoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more information.